# Where is the 'start a bounty'?

Tags: support, bounties

On [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/959242/how-is-next-hop-defined-in-routing-table) I asked a question and I wanted to start a bounty. The reason for this is because I need an answer quite fast and want to attract attention, but I can't find the 'start a bounty' button under my question.

[image: screen shot of question]

Comment: Wait another day

Comment: You must wait **2 days** before the link appears.